# I want to update my tablet OS

Tags: lubuntu, tablet, touchscreen

I want to update the operating system of my 8gb PendoPad Model:PNDPP4MT9G3
I spoke to Pendo recently and they informed me the model I have is outdated and incompatible.

I want to completely rework this tablet. & install lubuntu as the OS (I'd appreciate a how to walk-through), but since it is a touchscreen tablet I'm wondering what I can do to ensure the touchscreen will still work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult if not impossible to achieve. The PendoPad uses an ARM chip with a different instruction set to a normal CPU, which as far as I know is not compatible with any current versions of Ubuntu including Lubuntu. Even if it were compatible, I'm not sure how you'd install Lubuntu onto a device running android as there's no obvious equivalent of BIOS to set the boot preferences.